# TLS 1.2 on Windows Server 2003 and XP

Tags: wcf, ssl, transport-security

I have WCF service hosted on IIS which uses transport security. I need to restrict the TLS version to 1.2.

I found that TLS 1.2 is supported on Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7.

Can I restrict the usage of TLS to version 1.2 for Windows Server 2003 for the server and Windows Vista and XP for the client too? Is 1.2 supported for these older OSes?

Answer (score 2):

TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 are not supported by Win Server 2003, XP or Vista.  Applications which use the OS services for TLS will not be able to use TLS 1.1 or 1.2 on those platforms.

If you have an application, a browser or whatever, which handles in it's own TLS, then it could use TLS 1.1 or 1.2.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx